# Accessing Google API on Android

Tags: android

First of all i must tell that i am a beginner is this API stuff. I was trying to run a sample program according to what was described in this video at google IO.

Link to video and slides [Google Java API](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android)

I tried to build this sample program given the slides of this video

```
public class ExampleStart extends ListActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Buzz buzz = new Buzz(new NetHttpTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory());
    List<Spanned> activities = new ArrayList<Spanned>();
    try {
      ActivityFeed feed = buzz.activities.list("112550920411899420633", "@public").execute();
      if (feed.items != null)
        for (Activity activity : feed.items)
          activities.add(Html.fromHtml(activity.buzzObject.content));
      setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Spanned>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, activities));
    } catch (IOException e) {}
  }
}
```

but was not able to find Buzz or ActivityFeed classes. I added all the Jar files that i got from  google-api-java-client-1.6.0-beta.zip.(even the dependencies) However still i was not able to locate these classes.

I know all this code is doing is getting public buzz of a person and showing it as list.

I even tried looking at the samples provided by Google but all those were using maven and all i know about it, that it is something similar to Ant nothing more, So i was not able to use them.